# Wijmo Flexsheet Formula does not re-evaluate after referenced cell updated

Tags: angularjs, excel, wijmo

I am using wijmo 5 flexsheet with angularjs. 
Problem is like this.
Cell B3 has a formula "=SUM(B1+B2)" . When I update the value of B1 or B2 cell B3 does not recalculated.
If I edit cell B3 like "=SUm(B1+B2)" value is updated. After I reedit B1 or B2 again B3 is not updated. It's like formula string is cached.

Any idea how to resolve the issue?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

What's your Calculation option: If it is Automatically, it should update with the new value. Your option may be Manual?